# What's the best way to attach a hook to the back of my metal gutters?

Tags: installation

What's the best way to attach a hook to the back of my metal gutters? The hooks will be holding some Christmas lights.

Answer (score 4):

They sell clips like this

[image]

at the [Home Depot](http://www.homedepot.com), which can either clip under your singles or to the gutters.

*Not sure how well they work yet, I picked up a box and plan on giving them a try this year.*

Answer (score 2):

Not sure where you want to put the hook. Insn't the back of the gutter toward the house? Do you mean inside the gutter? Why would you put lights there. You can get plastic clips that go over the OUTSIDE of your gutter that hold lights. I wouldn't put any holes in the gutters with screws just for lights.

Comment: Tie wraps work well too